# Picking up correct cell value by mail script where ArrayFormula is applied

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I don't know anything about Google Scripts. All the scripts mentioned here under including the formulas have been researched on internet and improvised gradually. I need help of experts like you to achieve my outcomes. I am a beginner, hence please write your answer which I can understand. It would be great if you improve my script / formulas with brief explanation in simple language.

I have two sheets:

1) Form Response Sheet (linked to form)

2) DataBnak Sheet (importing form response data via query: `=query('Form Responses 3'!$A:$BH,"",1)`

I am using *ArrayFormula* in "DataBank" Sheet to create a unique text report based on values pulled  "Form Responses". This report needs to be emailed to each respondent upon form submit. the report is pulled in CH column thru (*ArrayFormula*), and once the mail is sent, I am marking "1" in CM column so to ensure duplicate mails are not sent every time the script runs.

`=ArrayFormula(IF(ROW($B:$B)=1,"Breif Report",IF(ISBLANK($B:$B),"",if(NOT(ISBLANK($CM:$CM)),"",iferror(vlookup(BU:BU&BV:BV&BW:BW&BX:BX,BriefProfile!$E:$F,2,0),"")))))`

Formula Explanation: where Cell in B column is not blank, and where cell in CM column is not blank (mail not sent), then bring the pre-written text based on the look-up value within columns (BU,BV,BW,BX).

What works correct:

1) The *ArrayFormula* works perfect (it pulls correct pre-written text)
2) Mail Script Works perfect (it sends to mails to those who have not been sent mail earlier)

What does not work:
1) The text report picked for a respondent is same for all respondents. When I remove *ArrayFormula* and ValuePaste the text report instead of calling it thru the formula mentioned above, then mail script picks up the correct unique report for each respondent and sends mail.

My mail script is mentioned below:

```
function sendEmails() { // Sends non-duplicate emails with data from the current spreadsheet.
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("DataBank");
    var Avals = sheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues(); // helps getting last fillled row^
    var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length; // helps getting last fillled row^
    var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
    var numRows = Alast-1; // Number of rows to process - last filled row^

    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 91);  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3 //.getrange(row,column,numRows,numColumns) numColumns should equal to max column number where data process is required.

  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[1]; // second column, actual column minus one
    var message = row[85]; // 85th column, actual column minus one
    var emailSent = row[90]; // 90th column, actual column minus one
    if (emailSent !== EMAIL_SENT) { // Prevents sending duplicates
      var subject = row[84] //'Sending emails from a Spreadsheet';
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 91).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      Utilities.sleep(120000); // keeps the script waiting untill the sheet gets updated values from "ArrayFormula"
    }
SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
  }
}
```

**Can you review my mail script and help me improve it so that it picks up correct unique report?**

Comment: What do you mean by `text report`? Do you mean the email message body that is picked from column 85?

Comment: Yes the email body is getting picked up from column 85.

Comment: To address column 85, you need to retrieve `var message = row[84];` since the first column would be `row[0]`.

Comment: Yes, actual row is 86, hence I have mentioned 85.

Comment: I cannot see any bug in your code, maybe you can provide a sample spreadsheet that reproduces the problem (please remove private information and replace recipient emails through fake values).

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it. declaring `var data = dataRange.getValues();` within the `for loop` solved my problem. I found the solution just now Thank you all!.

by declaring the variable before the for loop, I was actually storing the static data and the same was used in each iterations. When I declared the variable within for loop, the data started changing at each iteration.

Comment: I am glad you found a solution that works for you, but keep in mind that your solution is not necessary the most efficient one, because within every iteration you redefine your variable again (and to the same value!), which for long loops can take a considerate amount of time. Also,declaring var data within the for loop alone should not make any difference for the solution of the problem, maybe you redefined something else? Like e.g. replacing `i < data.length` through something else? I cn see a potential problem there - if you want to loop through columns, it should be `i < data[0].length`

Comment: Thank you for replying..Can you make change in the script mentioned in question and repost the entire new script with what you suggested for efficiency and ` i < data[0]. length `. It will be a big help because i am not even in a beginne grade in world.

Comment: To fully understand the problem with your script I would need to see a copy of your spreadsheet - please remove private information and replace personal data with dummy values.